# NRWL NX monorepo issue Nest JS prod build with Optimization Flag, Getting Invalid Class Name

Tags: nrwl-nx

I have build my own ORM library using TypeScript Decorators using NRWL(NX) + Nest JS. Getting invalid class name when using production build. Issue occurs for even printing class names to console

Issue observed only in create-nx-workspace@13.3.9

```
    export function Entity(): ClassDecorator {
      return (target) => {
        console.log('entity name............', target.name);
      };
    }

    @Controller()
    @Entity()
    export class AppController {
      constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {
        console.log('Class Name', AppController.name);
      }
    
      @Get()
      getData() {
        return this.appService.getData();
      }
    }
```

Optimization: true

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "inspect": false,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/test/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "apps/test/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Output:

```
entity name............ r
[Nest] 9276  - 19/12/2021, 5:47:37 am     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
Class Name r
[Nest] 9276  - 19/12/2021, 5:47:37 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] i dependencies initialized +26ms
[Nest] 9276  - 19/12/2021, 5:47:37 am     LOG [RoutesResolver] r {/api}: +7ms
[Nest] 9276  - 19/12/2021, 5:47:37 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api, GET} route +3ms
[Nest] 9276  - 19/12/2021, 5:47:37 am     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
[Nest] 9276  - 19/12/2021, 5:47:37 am     LOG  Application is running on: http://localhost:3333/api
```